# apt: install packages downloaded previously

Tags: debian, apt

On Debian, I can download a package plus its dependent packages with

```
apt-get install my_desired_package --download-only
```

This will not install the packages, but only download them to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. If I want to install the previously downloaded packages later, how would I do it (suppose I am offline)?

I can install one package with `dpkg -l package1` but only if all dependencies are met.

Comment: Can you install all of them using: `dpkg -l *`? I don't know, its just a guess.

Comment: @Kevdog777 Since they are downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives`, that wouldn't be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apt-get` always checks it's cache before performing a download. If the target package is available in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, then it will be installed from there and not downloaded. If the version has changed since you have done the download, you will have to specify the version manually.

```
apt-get install my_desired_package
apt-get install my_desired_package=1.0.1
```

Comment: Isn't that just installing them, when you are online? I thought the OP was saying to download them now, then install them at a later stage, when they are offline... no? Good answer though.

Comment: @Kevdog777 if the packages are downloaded already, and the version/sums fits what it's in the package list, apt-get won't try to connect to internet, so is like you are offline ;).

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that, TBH. Thanks :)